# Axios not sending as post method

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get a simple post form setup in React with Axios, but it doesn't seem to be sending as a post request for some reason, so Django keeps throwing a 405 error.

This is the react code that calls axios and handles the form:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    console.log('Form state: ', this.state);
    e.preventDefault();

    const username = this.state.username;
    const password = this.state.password;
    const formData = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    }
    // Django backend currently running on localhost:8000
    axios('http://localhost:8000/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
    }).then(res=> {
            console.log('res', res);
            console.log('res.data', res.data);
        }
    )

}
```

This is the django login view.  I have it required to be post, so it automatically throws the 405 error when not using post method.

Django:

```
import json, re
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_user
from django.contrib.auth import logout as logout_user
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from api.utils import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'api/home.html')


@csrf_exempt
@require_http_methods(['POST'])
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        if re.compile('.+@.+\..+').match(username):
            user = authenticate(email=username, password=password)
        else:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth_user(request, user)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(True), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            response = {
                'success': False,
                'error': True,
                'message': "The username/email or password was incorrect.",
            }
            return HttpResponseForbidden(json.dumps(response))

    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden("Post method required.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPTIONS request is a pre-flight request. See [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/475) for more details.

Your view is using `request.POST`, so expects the data to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. If you configure axios to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you won't have to configure CORS.

If you do use `application/json` then you'll have to configure CORS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to Django configuration of your app. Axios related code seems correct. Sample code of allowed https verbs.

```
class TheView(View):

self.allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'options']
def options(self, request, id):
    response = HttpResponse()
    response['allow'] = ','.join([self.allowed_methods])
    return response
```

Can you check your server configuration once.

Comment: Added the full code for the django view if that helps.

Comment: Also try for alternative react code. 


`axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });`

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Where do I put that in my `views.py`?  And do I just remove any methods from that list that I don't want a method to have access to?